# Apache 2.4 setenvif dontlog pingdom.com

Tags: regex, apache, logging, setenv

Many of webmasters use pingdom.com as a monitoring ping service.

But the problem is that /httpd/access_log is full of

```
208.64.28.194 - - [06/Aug/2015:12:20:22 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2917 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)"
```

I set

```
CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined env=!dontlog
```

and tried to get rid of it using variations like

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Host "^pingdom\.com$" dontlog
SetEnvIFNoCase Remote_Host "pingdom.com$" dontlog
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "www\.pingdom\.com" dontlog
SetEnvIFNoCase Host "^pingdom.com$" dontlog
```

but still no a success with any of them - so thanks for any else hint to try.

Comment: Have you enabled the setenv-module? Try the command $ sudo apache2ctl -M | grep setenv 

should return something like "setenvif_module (shared)"

And also, try
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "208\.64\.28\.194$" dontlog
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Pingdom" dontlog

Comment: Thanx, you solution `SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Pingdom" dontlog` works !

Answer (score 1):

I'll put my comment here as answer so anyone will find this easier.

Since one can see from the log file, the host name is not Pingdom.com but a part of the user agent string.

Solutions to try:
First be sure you have enabled the setenvif-module. Write the command

```
sudo apache2ctl -M | grep setenv
```

It should return something like "setenvif_module (shared)"

Then you can try setting by remote address

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "208\.64\.28\.194$" dontlog
```

The **final working solution is this**, dont log if the user agent string contains Pingdom string:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Pingdom" dontlog
```

Edit: enhanced some parts of the answer.

Comment: Use `httpd -M | grep setenv` on CentOS to check if setenvif-module is enabled